# Angular Material 6 - The background of some components appear transparent after changing the theme

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

When customizing the material angular theme, the background of components such as select, dialog and snackbar appear transparent, my sass code is:

```
@import '../../node_modules/@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

$default-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-cyan, 700);
$default-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-green, 600, A100, A400);
$default-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red, 700);

$default-app-theme: mat-light-theme($default-app-primary, $default-app-accent, $default-app-warn);
$no-login-app-theme: mat-dark-theme($default-app-primary, $default-app-accent, $default-app-warn);

$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Montserrat, sans-serif'
);

@include angular-material-typography($custom-typography);
@include angular-material-theme($default-app-theme);
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: No friend, they changed the priorities and the project was on standby. Surely when I return it will be Angular 20

Comment: anyone find a solution ? hit the same problem, but with angular 8 ;)